# storing datetime in python matrix

Tags: python, datetime, matrix

I have a 100 by 2 matrix. The first column has dates. in numerical format. The dates are not necessarily sequentially increasing or decreasing. The granularity of the dates is 5 minutes. Therefore, there could be rows whose year, month, day and hour are the same but their minutes are different. I need it to do some operations in the matrix, how can I do that? Is there any way to save date and time in the matrix?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please have a look at [ask]. As it stands, your question is a bit too general, maybe you could come up with a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that all depends on the data structure that you want to use:

- `numpy` has a dtype datetime: [doc here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html)
- `pandas` too: [tuto here](https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html)
- You can also choose to store them as unix timestamps, which are basically integers counting the number of seconds from 1/1/1970.
- If you choose to use builtin types instead such as lists and dictionaries, then you can use the library `datetime` which provides `datetime` objects.

If you want more information, a [simple google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20datetime) for "python datetime" will probably shed some light...

Comment: thank you, I know about DateTime and time module in python, but I don't know how to save data in a matrix

Comment: a matrix is not a programming concept as such, but suitable datastructures include arrays and dataframes, for this, I suggest that you look up how lists, pandas and numpy work